# iPhone app crashes when it automatically tries to login to a deleted account

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I built an app using Firebase, and I have persistenceEnabled turned on for caching data and auth sessions, etc.

I have a user who, every time he opens the app, it tries to login and load using the saved auth session, but his account was deleted, so it crashes.

He tried deleting the app, turning off the phone, even doing a hard reset by holding down the power and home button at the same time. But every time he opens the app, it still crashes on trying to load the persisted session data.

Is there any way to clear this data out short of restoring the phone back to its factory default settings or releasing a new version of the app?

Comment: you should probably add error handling for login, if it returns the error then you should clear the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Firebase stores account credentials in the keychain and there appears to be no way for the end user to remove them (see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509925/can-a-user-remove-a-keychain-item-from-his-ios-device)).

(If you're looking for a way to programmatically remove them, you should be able to call [ref unauth] or similar and Firebase will clear them.)